# Remote validation in jquery validation not returning

Tags: php, jquery

I have tried to get this to work and have  been unsuccessful, I have tried 18 different ways all produced the same result. I have double checked and triple check everything. NOTHING HAS WORKED! I have validation done server side as a fall back if jquery does not work. the validation part works fine its the cheeking if exists that is not working required is working.

> My form field

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" name="name" id="name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '' ?>">
      </div>
```

> My jquery vaidate function

```
$(function() {

  $("form[name='register']").validate({    
    rules: {

         name: {
              required: true,
              name: true,
              remote: {
                url: "../includes/check.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    name: function() {
                    return $( "#name" ).val();
                  }
                }
              }
            },


      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      password: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      }
    },

    messages: {

      name: {
          required: "Please enter your name",
          minlength: "Name must be at least 4 characters long",
          remote: "The name entered is unavailable"
          },

      password: {
        required: "Please provide a password",
        minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
      },
      email: "Please enter a valid email address"
    },

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

> My query script

```
include("db.php");

if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $db = dbconnect();
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT Name FROM users WHERE Name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows == 1){
        echo 'true';

    }else{
        echo 'false';
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/ is probably what you're looking for

Comment: @ADyson yes I updated my code but it does not check the user using remote

Comment: Well you'll have to give us a bit more debugging info than that. Does it fire your Ajax request? Does it succeed, what response do you get, etc?

Comment: Well thats all i can tell you it fires to make all fields requred it lights up red but as soon as I put a name that is in the database it removes the error of required from name field even though the name is taken var dump shows the name being pulled from the database.

Comment: Ill probably just stick with server side the client side seems to be to much of a headache validate is probably to old

Comment: So does your Ajax call return true or false? Don't give up, it should be possible to make it work.

Comment: Bear in mind according to the docs you have to return true when the entry is valid, and false when it's not. Your php seems to be doing the opposite

Comment: I guess i need to elaborate more, Ive tried switching echos didnt work i tried post didnt work i tried get didnt work ive tried 13 different remote settings didnt work even copied the code directly from the validate website didnt work tried 12 different code from 12 different websites didnt work i have tried everything it dont matter if you swap 1 for a 0 or rotate the echo true or false it dont work

Comment: "didnt work" means what though? Have you actually checked the status of the ajax call like I mentioned? Do you understand what I mean by that (i.e. looking in your developer tools in the browser to see the status)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to the remote validation.

You just need to remove

```
name: true,
```

from your validation options. This option does not exist in jQuery Validate - there is no validation metod called "name" - and causes a Javascript error when jQuery validate tries to use it:

> Cannot read property 'call' of undefined.  Exception occurred when checking element name, check the 'name' method.

This means that the "remote" validation never executes because the script crashes before it gets to it.

See https://jsfiddle.net/09djba33/10/ to see the broken functionality - open the Developer Tools and submit the form (with the name field completed), and watch the error message appear in the console.

and https://jsfiddle.net/09djba33/12/ to see the "remote" method working correctly without that spurious option.

P.S. This is why, in the comments, I kept asking you to check what was happening to your ajax request, by looking in the browser tools... :-)

Comment: I woke up with a fresh perspective  the name: true fixed it but on all the documents it said it should be there

Comment: Interesting, which documentation did you see which told you to use that? It's not shown in the list of methods at https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ . Of course it's possible to extend the validator with custom methods but obviously that requires extra code.

Answer (score -2):

From reading the docs https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/ you can see that while using remote, you need to send data to your server side script because you are using post method. Do it in this way :

```
remote: {
                url: "../includes/check.php",
                type: "post"
                data: {
                username: function () {
                     return $('#username').val(); 
                }
        },
```